# Laravel - devolver campo calculado

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-6

tengo un modelo de datos que se llama "**Cars**" que tiene un atributo que es "type" que toma valores del 1 al 6. Por ejemplo 1 es compacto , 2 berlina , 3 superdeportivo, etc..

En el modelo tengo lo siguiente

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cars extends Model
{
    CONST type_compacto = 1;
    CONST type_berlina = 2
    CONST type_superdeportivo = 3;

    protected $fillable = [
        'id','name','description', 'type','enabled'
    ];
}
```

Y si por ejemplo hago una consulta con eloquent de este tipo

```
$cars = Cars::where('enabled',1)->get();
```

Esto me devuelve una colección donde el atributo "type" me devuelve 1..2..3... si quiero que me devuelva el tipo (el literal. Ejemplo...compacto..superdeportivo), como debería hacerlo?

Gracias

Comment: Puedes utilizar un switch dependiendo el valor que te regrese

Comment: Puedes hacer un modelo Type con esas ids y nombres, y usar la columna `type` de Car como llave foránea para hacer la relación.

Comment: gracias @porloscerrosΨ, algún ejemplo de esto? la idea la he entendido pero no veo como hacerlo.